# How do I whiten near-white areas without going near darker ones?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I scan a lot of books, and it's my practice to keep the raw TIFF files forever. I do lossless compression, but the compression is terrible because the vast white areas of the document (margins, between paragraphs etc.) are in fact *near-white*.  The whitespace is actually random numbers in the range 242-255, which compress poorly.

Manually, in Photoshop, I select rectangles of white areas that will never need revisiting, and blank them (backspace). This is tedious but makes the document take 1/2 to 1/5 the space.

I'd rather automate this. I can see the code in my head: it sets to white any pixel where all pixels within 5px of it are near-white. That leaves an untouched margin around the stuff I care about preserving raw.

But how do I code or automate this? Here, I have access to Photoshop CS2 and a Unixlike platform (MacOS 10.5 on PPC, Terminal windows open at all times) and know several coding languages and can learn whichever one is called for.  Later I'll have access to CS5 and OS X 10.11.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't merely increase the white point in the scan entirely via a **Levels or Curves adjustment*? Heck even Threshold or Brightness/Contrast would work.

Comment: In some of my scans, that will wash out the insides of desirable content.  I won't know which until I get into manually handling it later.

Comment: Well, that's probably going to be an issue with any automation. If you want to adjust the white point of only some, unknown, areas, that's difficult to automate using any method.

Comment: I can reliably blank large open areas.  But for instance I don't want to blank white pixels between letters or in the middle of a halftone. Hence my desire for a left-alone margin around non-white things.  This isn't the actual, final image processing of the images, that will come later and be more hands-on.

Comment: The problem is you can't create a "margin" within a field of the same tone. So there would be no automated method I'm aware of, short of contracting a selection, that would create any "margin". And, of course, contracting would contract all the way around the selection not merely for one "side" or "direction".